# What should our about page contain?

Tags: discussion

Moderators can edit the [tour page (formerly called the about page)](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour) of a site. We can change the "ask about" and "don't ask about" sections of the page.

Here's the current content:

> #### Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with earth science
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
>
> #### Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to earth science
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Is there anything that we should add? Anything that we should remove or change? Feedback welcome!

Comment: You should probably pick a good question from the site to replace the unicorn one and then ask the CM team to replace it.

Comment: +1 @Seth: "I love the unicorns who hang out behind my kitchen, but they do tend to eat rather a lot of the daisies. What can I do about this?"

Comment: What are the minimum / maximum numbers of bullet points for the ask / don't ask about sections?

Comment: @BHF I just tried, and I got ten bullets on one section. So 10+ bullets per section.

Comment: I dunno, I reckon daisies are probably on-topic, as long as you're looking at the ecological impact...

Answer (score 7):

I would like to see a very brief hint for usage of discipline tags. For example if we could replace / modify

> All questions are tagged with their subject areas. Each can have up to 5 tags, since a question might be related to several subjects.

with

> All questions are tagged with their subject areas. Each can have up to 5 tags. This allows you to combine discipline tags with more question specific tags, e.g. meteorology with tropical-cyclone.

Comment: That would be nice, but we can't edit that part. Any ideas? (we can edit the top part, and the two things in my post)

Comment: Well if that editing is wanted, we can ask the stack exchange staff to consider it. Let's first see how opinion making turns out.

Comment: @BHF perhaps bring it up on [meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com)? There it would get much more attention and something like that might get pushed to all the sites.

Answer (score 0):

***Help docs:*** Hey! What about [me](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Don't forget that you need to edit that, too :P

---

The about page should give the user a general idea of the scope of the site, not for the minor details. I haven't been around here long enough to suggest a full revision, but here are some details;

- Something about weather patterns (i.e. Ask about [topic], weather patterns, rocks, and [topic]). I know that draft sounds *really* dull, but I don't know that much about your community.

  - What I'm trying to get at is you should have something like this:

    > Specific issues with Arduino boards, clones, code, and the Arduino IDE

  (Stolen from Arduino SE... I wrote this)
- You might want to also mention that it's *not* a place for general sciences/chemistry...

You don't have to get into too much detail, just something you might tell someone who was passing by and asked, *What is Earth Sciences SE all about?*

---

***Pssst!*** Change the unicorn-daisy question if there's a question that qualifies for tour worthiness... although it's a nice question, too.

Comment: There's no eligible question for the tour question... somehow I'm betting that's because we like having long answers & questions, with "weird formatting" (pictures).

Comment: @hichris Ahh... a "quirky SE site?" Anyway, it's often tough to get a good question for the tour page.